# Airflow DAG task not found after updating adding a task

Tags: airflow

I'm having trouble updating a dag file. Dag still have an old version of my dag file. I added a task but it seems not updated when I check the log and UI (DAG->Code).

I have very simple tasks.
I of course checked the dag directory path in `airflow.cfg` and restarted `airflow webserver/scheduler`.
I have no issue running it (but with the old dag file).

Comment: In my case it was due to two different dag files in dags folder with the same dag_id. Airflow didn't throw any error, but it was picking up one of these dags arbitrarily.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bug of airflow. A temp solution is to delete the task instances from airflow db by

`delete from task_instance where dag_id=<dag_name> and task_id=<deleted_task_name>';`

This should be simpler and less impactful than the resetdb route which would delete everything including variables and connections set before.

Comment: This worked for me. (`resetdb` doesn't even blow everything away for me, for some reason.) I had updated a DAG, deleting old tasks and creating new ones. When running the new version of the DAG, I got an `AirflowException` referencing the old task that no longer existed. I deleted rows referencing that task in the metadata DB, per @Lily. I'm new to Airflow, so I don't know if the best practice is to completely rename the py DAG file for each version, so that there's no namespace confusion in the metadata DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the old .pyc file for that dag in the dags folder and generate it again.

Comment: Can you check again that the latest updated file exists in the dags folder specified in the config? Removing previously compiled files should force it to recompile the dag, hence updating the code.

Answer (score 0):

UI sometimes is not up to date to me, but the code is actually there in dag bag. You can try to:

1. Use refresh button to see if code refreshed
2. Use higher version 1.8+, this happens to me before when I used 1.7.X, but after 1.8+, it seems much better after you refresh dag in UI
3. You can also use "airflow test" to see if the code is in place, and try the advice from @Him as well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment! I tried 1-3 but it is actually still an old DAG and UI doesn't show the new file either...

Comment: What's your executor? I think run only support with celery

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me.

In the end the best thing is to "resetdb", add connections and import variables again and then airflow initdb and set the scheduler back again.

I don't know why this happens. Anybody knows? It seems not so easy to add tasks or change names once compiled. Removing *.pyc or logs folder did not work for me.

Comment: Fix this please. It is REALLY annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Use terminal and run the below command soon after changing the dag file.

```
airflow initdb
```

This worked for me.

Comment: `airflow db init` ?

Answer (score 0):

In DAG page of Airflow webserver, delete the DAG. It will delete the record in the database. After a while the DAG will appear again in the page, but the old task_id is removed.